# Read a GeometryCollection from a string

Tags: openlayers-3

in OpenLayers 3 I can read Features or a single Geometry from a GeoJSON string through an instance of `ol.format.GeoJSON()`.
Example:

```
var parser = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var arrOfFeatures = parser.readFeatures(geoJsonString);
//or
var usrGeom = parser.readGeometry(geoJsonString);
```

Now I have a string representing a GeometryCollection (not a MultiPoint, MultiLine or MultyPolygon, nor a FeatureCollection).

I cannot find a way to `readGeometryCollection(GeoJSONstring)` or something, having an `ol.geom.GeometryCollection` object as the result.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about showing this string?

Comment: Have a look at this geojson example on the OL3 example page: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html

One of the geometries in the example geojsonObject has `'type': 'GeometryCollection'`

Is this what you are searching for?

Comment: Yes, but in the example the string is passed directly in the vector source, while in my case I need to parse a general GeoJSON string. As far as I know, a GeometryCollection might be even not wrapped in a Feature. http://geojsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution was to read a GeometryCollection just like any other Openlayers ol.geom.Geometry and then loop to read any single geometry, so: 1)read the string into a Geometry object, 2) if .getType() is "GeometryCollection" then loop the collection, and forEach(item) in the collection read the Geometry.

```
parseSingleGeometry : function(geometry, callback) {

        switch (geometry.getType()) {
            case 'MultiLineString':
                geometry.getLineStrings().forEach(function (p) {
                    var newFeat = new ol.Feature({ geometry: p });
                    _features.push(newFeat);
                });
                break;
            case 'MultiPolygon':
                geometry.getPolygons().forEach(function (p) {
                    var newFeat = new ol.Feature({ geometry: p });
                    _features.push(newFeat);
                });
                break;
            case 'Polygon':
            case 'LineString':
            case 'Point':
                var newFeat = new ol.Feature({ geometry: geometry });
                _features.push(newFeat);
                delete newFeat;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (callback) { callback(); }

    },

    parseGeometryCollection: function(collection, callback) {

        var ciccio = new ol.geom.GeometryCollection();
        //ciccio.getType
        var itemCount = ciccio.getGeometries().length;
        var itemProg = 0;

        ciccio.getGeometries().forEach(function (item) {
            parseSingleGeometry(item, function () {

                itemProg++;
                if (itemProg == itemCount) {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback();
                    }
                }                
            })
        });
    }
```

[...]

```
importGeoJson: function (geoJsonString) {

        var parser = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

        var projection = parser.readProjection(geoJsonString);
        var usrProjCode = projection.getCode();

        var convert = false;

        if (usrProjCode != 'EPSG:3857') {
            var msg = "The file provided is in the " + usrProjCode + " projection. The system supports the EPSG:3857 projection only.\n\rWe are converting your geometries in EPSG:3857.\n\rPlease visually check that the added shapes are what your file defines.";
            alert(msg);
            convert = true;
        }

        //if it's a feature or feature collection than I can readFeatures()
        if (geoJsonString.indexOf("Feature") !== -1) {

            console.log("reading feature(s)");

            var arrOfFeatures = parser.readFeatures(geoJsonString);

            arrOfFeatures.forEach(function (item) {

                var usrGeom = item.getGeometry();

                var newGeom = (convert) ? usrGeom.clone().transform(usrProjCode, 'EPSG:3857') : usrGeom;

                if (newGeom.getType() == "GeometryCollection") {
                    _private.parseGeometryCollection(newGeom, function () { /*do something*/ })
                }
                else {
                    _private.parseSingleGeometry(newGeom, function () { /*do something*/ });
                }
            });
        }
        else { //otherwise work with geometries

            var usrGeom = parser.readGeometry(geoJsonString);

            var newGeom = (convert) ? usrGeom.clone().transform(usrProjCode, 'EPSG:3857') : newGeom;

            if (newGeom.getType() == "GeometryCollection") {
                _private.parseGeometryCollection(newGeom, function () { /*do something*/ })
            }
            else {
                _private.parseSingleGeometry(newGeom, function () { /*do something*/ });
            }
        }

    },
```

_features is the ol.Collection containing the features showed on the map.